# MySQL Delete with join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, myisam

I have 2 tables, both MyISAM. Table 'dataproc' with 600000 records, and table 'unsubscribers' with 2500 records. I'm trying delete the records from table a when field x in table A matches matches field y in table b. The query I have written, whilst it works, is VERY slow (30mins+).

```
DELETE e 
FROM dataproc e 
INNER JOIN unsubscribers j ON e.EMAIL = j.EMAIL;
```

I wrote one similar that had a LEFT join on an membership number field with a WHERE e.EMAIL = j.EMAIL and it ran faster but unfortunately didn't have the same results (as not all of the membership numbers had the same email addresses). Though this query ran a lot faster than the one above, it completed in seconds.

To get the entire delete to be as fast as the second query I wrote, do I need to JOIN on 1 or both fields that are indexed? Is there a better way to write the first query so that it is fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try the `EXISTS()` version of this, might be slightly faster:

```
DELETE FROM dataproc e 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM unsubscribers j WHERE e.EMAIL = j.EMAIL);
```

30 Minutes sounds like a lot for 600k records, I believe this can be solved with the use of proper indexes(If you don't have them yet)

Consider adding index on column `EMAIL` on both `unsubscribers` and `dataproc` , if they are not there yet, it should significantly improve your performances.

Comment: Thanks! While I never tried the query, creating indexes on the two fields worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

If `LEFT JOIN` is more faster, how about following;)

```
DELETE e 
FROM dataproc e 
LEFT JOIN unsubscribers j ON e.EMAIL = j.EMAIL
WHERE j.EMAIL IS NOT NULL
```

And `INDEX` is necessary for improve performance.

Comment: Actually, it won't necessarily be faster, what if `dataproc` contain all of `unsubscribers` records ? Then it won't have any effect.

Comment: @sagi Absolutely yes, as your answer said, `index` will be necessary, my answer is definitely not a perfect solution.

Comment: I didn't talk about the index, I was talking about what you said on `LEFT JOIN`'s

Comment: Yeah, I know what you said, and I also agreed with you. My answer is just based on the description of question, this may not be even an answer, but for a suggestion, author may do have some try, isn't it? Or I can delete this one;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add non clustered index on email field in tables.

```
     ALTER TABLE dataproc ADD INDEX index_one (email)
     ALTER TABLE unsubscribers ADD INDEX index_one (email)
```